# Scrolling tape of videos in react native like in tiktok or youtube shorts

Tags: react-native, video, scroll, expo, scrollview

I tried to use flatList, ScrollView and "react-native-reanimated-carousel" library, but unfortunately I can't create such "sticky" scroll. I want to scroll on the next element only when user overcomes a specific scroll distance and when he overcomes a smaller scroll distance, he need to return on the current video, like in tiktok or youtube shorts.

"react-native-reanimated-carousel" library is very close, but I couldn't create return on the preqious element if scroll distance is smaller.

Some of my code:

"react-native-reanimated-carousel" library:

```js
<Carousel
   defaultIndex={currentItem}
   enabled={isCarouselScroll}
   loop={false}
   width={width}
   height={videoHeight - 60}
   vertical
   data={dataForVideos}
   onSnapToItem={(index) => setCurrentVideo(index)}
   renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
     <View key={index}>
       <VideoItem  lessonId={lessonsIds[index]} navigation={navigation} current={currentVideo === index} url={videoUrls[index]} />
     </View>
   )}
/>
```

FlatList and  ScrollView:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, PanResponder, FlatList, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const videoWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const videoHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const TikTokScroll = () => {
  const itemHeight = videoHeight; 
  const [scrollDistance, setScrollDistance] = useState(0);
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);

  const data = ['content1', 'content1 2', 'content1 3'];

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => scrollToIndex(index)}>
      <View style={{ height: itemHeight, borderWidth: 2, width: videoWidth }}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
      setScrollDistance(gestureState.dy);
    },
  });

  const scrollToIndex = (index) => {
    flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index });
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={flatListRef}
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
      scrollEnabled={true}
    />
  );
};

export default TikTokScroll;
```